# API Bluetooth Low Energy no windows store app?

Tags: sockets, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

is it possible to use API BLE in a Windows service or a winform app ?

I need a app for get data from BLE devices and after communicate with a chrome app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 different technics :

- Use the Windows >=8 Win32 API directly with DllImport or through a C++ DLL that will expose simplified functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450802(v=vs.85).aspx
- Use the Windows >=8 WinRT API in your WinForms app using this technique https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have tested your second idea but API Win RT for desktop app have restriction and I can't connect bluetooth device with this API.
I don't have experience for DllImport or C++, I will try this solution but do you have maybe a example ?